# How do you hide labels in a form class in symfony2?

Tags: php, forms, class, symfony

I know that you can split a form out in twig and choose to not render the label for a particular field, but I can't help but think that you must be able to do this from the form class. The 'label' key in the options array lets you change this value to whatever you like, but passing either false or an empty string just returns the field name (see examples below where 'roles' is rendered as the label).

```
$builder
            ->add('roles', 'entity', array(
                'class' => 'Acme\UserBundle\Entity\Role',
                'label' => '' 
            ));

$builder
            ->add('roles', 'entity', array(
                'class' => 'Acme\UserBundle\Entity\Role',
                'label' => false 
            ));
```

Strangely, passing an empty space (which feels very dirty) seems to render a completely empty label, with no space even when viewing the source. Can anyone shed any light on the best approach, or even why the empty space seems to work?

Comment: Correction, there was no way to do this for Symfony 2.0.x but cheesemacfly has provided the correct answer versions 2.2+.

Answer (score 122, accepted):

Since Symfony 2.2 you can avoid the `<label>` rendering using the `false` value for the `label` attribute:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('Name', null, array('label' => false))
    ;
}
```

[Source](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/commit/36e455680549bfe9fa5b1282e95bb9b36f2220be#src/Symfony/Bridge/Twig/Resources/views/Form/form_div_layout.html.twig)

Comment: Thanks for this. I had originally asked the question in relation to a 2.0.x project, but since I have not specified a version I think this is the right answer. Also, since it's a new addition there was clearly no way to do it in the earlier versions from the form class, so this will hopefully help people with similar issues.

Comment: @Mark Funny enough, it is available in 2.0.x since today: http://symfony.com/blog/symfony-2-0-23-released (I swear I have nothing to do with it :D )

Comment: Ha. In that case this is most definitely definitely the correct answer. It might be worth adding that to your answer in case someone doesn't read the comments and upgrades their whole application to 2.2 just to get this awesome functionality :)

Comment: I was wrong, it was changed to solve [another bug](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/6862). Sorry...

Comment: Related item-- if you want to use HTML 5 placeholder text instead of the label, use 'attr' => array('placeholder'=>'Your Name') in the form builder array after the label=>false.

Comment: Its better to keep your 'View' specifications separate from your 'Model'. Added an answer below.

Answer (score 20):

> Keep your 'View' specifications separate from your 'Model'

If you follow the accepted answer which says:

```
$builder
        ->add('Name', null, array('label' => false))
    ;
```

your form is not as re-usable. Especially if your form appears in more than one location (or might in the future).

If you do not want to render the form label it is best to do so in **Twig** (assuming your using Twig).

instead of rendering `{{ form_row(form.name) }}`, render each element separetly and exclude the `form_label`

ex.

```
{{ form_errors(form.name) }}
 {# {{ form_label(form.name) }} <-- just dont include this #} 
{{ form_widget(form.name) }}
```

If down the road you wanted the label in one instance of the form but the not the other, simply adding `{{ form_label(form.name) }}` would suffice; Where as changing `array('label' => true)` would turn the label on everywhere

If you are rendering your form with the one liner `{{ form(form) }}` then you should have a look at the [symfony docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#form-rendering-template)

Comment: I fully agree with this supplement.

Comment: However, there is a small downside with this: if you are using a layout (such as bootstrap_3_horizontal_layout), you can break it and get rendering issues. I would suggest OP to overwrite the layout for his form (it's quite easy : [cf. Symfony documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_customization.html))

Comment: It's not often you reuse forms tho. Different pages have different requirements and often you just end up with a new form class and new object class to pass in.

Answer (score 13):

Just add {'label':false} to your form_row()

```
{{ form_row(form.name, {'label':false}) }}
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't understand very well your question but in form to show the name of label,personnaly I do like that  :

```
  $builder
        ->add('role', 'text')
```

in my twig  :

```
    <tr>
        <td>{{ form_widget(form.role) }} </td>
        <td>{{ form_label(form.role, "Name of Label") }}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>{{ form_errors(form.role) }}</td>
    </tr>
```

Answer (score 3):

To hide my label, I had to render just the widget for the field, and not the label, e.g.

```
{{ form_widget(edit_form.event) }}
{{ form_rest(edit_form) }}
```

The problem with the ' ' label with a space in, is that it still renders the html input which is there and affects the page.

Comment: This way is better because it does not put 'View' specifications inside your Model. you may also want to add `{{ form_errors(form.name) }}` if you would like to keep errors.

Answer (score 2):

this should work (although its not a very clean solution)

```
$builder
        ->add('roles', 'entity', array(
            'class' => 'Acme\UserBundle\Entity\Role',
            'label' => ' ' 
        ));
```

(note the space between the ticks)

Comment: Thanks for this, but you'll notice I mention this solution beneath my code snippet in the question