# Why is my custom form theme inserting a label twice?

Tags: symfony, twig

I'm trying to create a simple [custom form theme](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_themes.html#creating-your-own-form-theme) but I'm having trouble with the [form_label](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_customization.html#form-label-form-view-label-variables) function.

The form:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('mobile', TextType::class, [
                'label' => 'Cell number',
            ]);
}
```

The template that is created in the controller:

```
{{ form(form) }}
```

The theme:

```
{% use 'form_div_layout.html.twig' %}
{% block text_widget %}
    <div class="card_box">
        <div class="row">
            {{ form_errors(form) }}
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-3">
                <label>{{ form_label(form) }}</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-9">
                {{ form_widget(form, {'attr': {'class': 'full'}}) }}
                <small>{{ form_help(form) }}</small>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

I expected the HTML output to be something like

```
<form method="post" name="form">
    <div id="form">
        <div class="card_box">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-3">
                    <label class="required" for="form_mobile">Cell number</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-9">
                    <input class="full" id="form_mobile" name="form[mobile]" required="required" type="text"/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

The actual output includes a duplicate label before the `<div class="card-box">`:

```
<form method="post" name="form">
    <div id="form">
        <div>
            <label class="required" for="form_mobile">Cell number</label>
            <div class="card_box">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-3">
                        <label class="required" for="form_mobile">Cell number</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-9">
                        <input class="full" id="form_mobile" name="form[mobile]" required="required" type="text"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Omitting the form_label call removes the second label but the first (undesirable) label still appears.
This is a theme that will be applied site-wide, so I don't want to have to edit the form_label every time this happens.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you hide labels in a form class in symfony2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10602923/how-do-you-hide-labels-in-a-form-class-in-symfony2)

Comment: you are overriding the `text_widget` block(only), with html for the whole `text_row` try `{% block text_row %}`